# Recyclerview item losing focus on NotifyItemChange

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility-api, notifyitemchanged

When NotifyItemChanged() is called, the item that currently has accessibility focus loses it and the accessibility focus goes to the top of the screen. I have debugged onBindViewHolder and it doesn’t change the focus. Is there something else that NotifyItemChanged() calls after this that would affect accessibility focus?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but sending a payload will keep the focus on the item. Even just an empty string does the trick.

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position, "")
```